# Django, how to update model in save() method after calling a super()?

Tags: python, django, django-models, save, overriding

I have such problem. For example, there is a field in my model class:

```
periodic_task = models.OneToOneField(PeriodicTask, null=True, blank=True)
```

I need to override the `save()` method to set this field value:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PostTweetSet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.periodic_task = TaskScheduler.create(
        'tweets.tasks.post_next_tweet', self.interval.period,
        self.interval.every, args="[" + '"%s"' % str(self.pk) + "]")
```

You see that `self.periodic_task` gets assigned after actually calling the `super()` method. I did so, because of need to have a pk field (I use it in `TaskScheduler` create method). On the other side, I need to update db-table for this model after setting this new field. If I call `super()` once again, I'll get error about duplicating id. So, what can I do to make this work? Or I need to reconstruct my approach for this task at all? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to do something like this:

`super(PostTweetSet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
 self.periodic_task = TaskScheduler.create(
 'tweets.tasks.post_next_tweet', self.interval.period,
 self.interval.every, args="[" + '"%s"' % str(self.pk) + "]")
 kwargs.update({'update_fields': ['periodic_tweet']})
 super(PostTweetSet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

but get error - `ValueError: Cannot force both insert and updating in model saving.`

Answer (score 6):

**I'd do it with a post-save signal.**

*If you can't* or that's otherwise unappealing, you think about your requirement as two paths:

- if you don't the primary key, you need to save it first and get the pk
- if you already know the primary key, you can create your periodic task and then call super

So something like (pseudocode):

```
def save(...):
    if self.pk is None:
        super(...)
        self.save(...)    # Call ourselves -- but this time, we'll have a primary key!
    else:
        ... create your periodic task
        super(...)
```

Answer (score 4):

By providing some condition in the `override save method` in model I have achieved same requirement.

In the question, requirement is to update the `periodic_task` field after saving the model, so here is the sudo code structure I have followed:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    periodic_task = models.OneToOneField(PeriodicTask, null=True, blank=True)
    def save(self):
        super(Asset, self).save()
        if not self.periodic_task: # Checking if the section is not updated.
            self.periodic_task = #code to update the field.
            self.save() #again call the save.
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to do this in the `post_save` signal instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `super()` at the end of your `save()` override.  Here is an example using the `slugify()` method.  The slugify method turns a string into a slug by converting all characters to lowercase and spaces to dashes.  Here's the code:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't believe this allows you to know the instance's primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a signal, why not store the result of `super()` and return it instead of the call itself?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    run_task = False
    if not self.pk:
        run_task = True

    result = super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    if run_task:
        TaskScheduler.create(...)

    return result
```